# How to get text from a table in PHP and display that text in the subject of an email via mailto link

Tags: php, mailto

I have a form on a website that contains a table with a title and a reference. At the bottom of this form I have a submit button that I want to create a mailto link that opens up an email with the "From" field auto filled with the users email address that they have entered in the form. I would also like to auto fill the "Subject" field with the title and reference elements from the table on the form.

Could someone please tell me how to go about this using PHP?

Comment: Please provide your code here.

Answer (score 0):

See also [Mailto Syntax Tutorial](http://www.addressmunger.com/mailto_syntax_tutorial/).

When generating this link, you will need to use the same PHP statements you use in the table.

Because you haven't provided any code, here's a general approach to the matter.

Say for example, your table is populated

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Title:</td>
    <td><?php echo $data['title']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Reference:</td>
    <td><?php echo $data['ref']; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You would have to create the link:

```
<a href="mailto:email@domein.com?subject=<?php echo $data['title']; ?> - ref. <?php echo $data['ref']; ?>">Send mail</a>
```